# TeamCity XML Report Processing difference between code inspections

Tags: teamcity, findbugs, teamcity-9.0

i use findbugs, and i found checkbox "inspections with new problems only" which shows only difference between current and previous build. Do you know where teamcity stores the old result ?

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity stores inspection results and tests produced by xml report processing in the database